# how to avoid duplicate import and component declarations in VueJS

Tags: import, vue.js

I'm using Quasar and the PWA starter kit, with VueJS.

I want to know how to declare once a set of components used throughout many pages in a Vue app.

I seem to need to have a huge import declaration in every page

I tried to import once in `main.js` but there is a conflicting

```
import Quasar from 'quasar'
```

so I can't add to that or change it to

```
import {
  Quasar,
  QCard,
  .... etc
 } from 'quasar'
```

as the {} seems to break the import.
Also can't import twice (`duplicate import` error).

What is the way to import components once for a whole app?
Or get at the Vue object so it can be used in another way to import inside a different component?

Answer (score 2):

You can import specific components to register globally in the `main.js` file when you register the `Quasar` plugin.

For example, in you want to be able to use the `<q-btn>` and `<q-icon>` components anywhere in your application you could do this:

```
import Quasar, { QBtn, QIcon } from 'quasar'

Vue.use(Quasar, {
  components: { QBtn, QIcon }
})
```

[Here's the documentation.](http://quasar-framework.org/components/introduction-for-beginners.html)